# The word "stuff": possible combinations of words

Tags: collocations

> Good/great/lovely stuff!

These are collocations used for praising something. Can the combination of words "nice stuff" be used along with them?

Comment: Please give more context on questions like this. What is "something"? Tobacco?  Marijuana?  15 year-old Scotch?  A term paper?  Charcoal sketches?  Garden fertilizer? Recordings of Bach?

Comment: Some sentences written in the very neat and easily readable handwriting :)

Comment: In AmE, "great stuff!" can refer to the *content* of what was written, but not to the penmanship itself, not unless the writing was an assemblage of calligraphic exercises or similar.

Comment: Some sentences are an assemblage, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nice stuff** makes sense, but it means "nice things".  It is typically used as part of a sentence rather than as an exclamation - and if we did say "**nice stuff!**" as an exclamation, it would probably be in reference to some specific things.

**Good stuff** or **great stuff** or **lovely stuff** is used as an exclamation meaning "nice job!", "good work!", "good to hear!", etc, expressing satisfaction at a situation or at some news rather than referring to any tangible or specific objects.  "Nice stuff" isn't used as an exclamation in that way.

Comment: Thank you. I find it interesting since the adjective "lovely" means the same as "nice" does - "enjoyable, attractive".

Comment: **Good stuff** et al. may be a British or Commonwealthism - it sounds odd to this USAnian.

Comment: @stangdon - True, I agree – although it works in some contexts, such as where the "stuff" is intangible. (For example, if a comedian is in the middle of a good routine, or someone is sharing some juicy office gossip. In those cases, I can imagine someone saying, "This is good stuff!")

Comment: @J.R. - True, it still works perfectly well if there is in fact "stuff"; I was a little too broad in my statement.  It just isn't a generic (US) replacement for "good to hear", is all I meant.